# Azure Logic App - Composing converts to string but I need one value as "float" - Will not let me convert

Tags: azure, http, type-conversion, azure-logic-apps

I'll try to summarize it without a lot of text, this is my issue:

I have a parse Json action

After that comes a "For Each" loop that has a "Compose" action and a "HTTP POST" action.

The compose action has 12 values that it is composing from my parse json action.
One of these 12 values is "livingspace" and equals to 51.5 and has to be set as a "float" or "number".

The next action is a "HTTP POST" action where I want to send the body my data from the compose action  to an API.
The API will not accept my data because "livingspace" value is too low. When I look through the logs it says that "livingspace" is "51.5"
Before composing the value, "livingspace" is 51.5 in green numbers. This turns into a string when it goes through the compose action

I tried simply converting it in the compose action like this:

```
"livingspace": "int(items('For_each')?['Kontraktsarea'])",
```

I then tried:

```
"livingspace": "float(items('For_each')?['Kontraktsarea'])",
```

---

When converting to INT I did not expect it to work since the value comes out with decimals. And I get an error saying "
The template language function 'int' was invoked with a parameter that is not valid. The value cannot be converted to the target type."

When converting to Float I get past the "compose" action and onwards to the HTTP POST action where it fails again. It fails because "Livingspace" is too low of a value. When I check the output the "Livingspace" has turned into a string again.

I'm kind of lost on what to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest removing the quotes.  Change it from this ...

```
"livingspace": "float(items('For_each')?['Kontraktsarea'])"
```

... to this ...

```
"livingspace": float(items('For_each')?['Kontraktsarea'])
```

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I don't have the quotes in my command as it would not run like that, I'm not sure why I entered it in this text that I wrote above but I am currently sending it like this: 

float(items('For_each')?['Kontraktsarea'])

Comment: You need to provide some screenshots and a sample data set then.

Comment: This actually solved my issue...
The expression itself did not have " ", but the " " was around the expression which caused it to become a string value.

I tried removing them as you said and now they give me a float number as I wanted.

The problem was on my end, small mistake. Thanks for providing your input.